# Ngx-tawk throwing error Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error: Unexpected token 'ID'

Tags: angular6

I added the ngx-tawk template to my app.component.html to my lazy-loaded application.

```
  <!--app.component.html-->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <ngx-tawk [id]="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></ngx-tawk>
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' at column 2 in [5bb4aa97b033e9743d021435] in ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@2:10 ("ent below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<ngx-tawk [ERROR ->][id]="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"></ngx-tawk>
```

The XXXXXXXXXXXXX is id provided by tawk.io

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thank You @halfer I decided to go with livechat/angular-livechat https://github.com/livechat/angular-livechat for anyone who needs quick way of intergrating livechat in the angular applications.